# How to display search results in admin theme?

Tags: search

I want to start using the search function in my admin area. I googled quite a lot, but i couldn't find away to display the search results in the admin theme. Anyone any idea's how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

At the code level you can use [`hook_admin_paths()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7), e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_admin_paths() {
  return array(
    'search/*',
  );
}
```

Or if you'd rather use a non-code solution, you could install a module like [ThemeKey](https://drupal.org/project/themekey)

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties.

Comment: I can't accept you're answer as accepted, but themekey seemed to be the right anser for me. Thanx!